# Github Action not passing step env variable

Tags: github-actions, vite

I have the following job:

```yaml
  deploy:
      name: Build webapp
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      environment: Production
      steps:
        - name: Checkout action
          uses: actions/checkout@v2

        - name: Install npm dependencies
          run: npm ci

        - name: Build
          run: npm run build
          env:
            VITE_SECRET_I_NEED: ${{ secrets.VITE_SECRET_I_NEED }}
```

- I have tried saving it both as a "Environment secrets" and "Repository secrets"
- I have tried `${{ env.VITE_SECRET_I_NEED }}` also

The built file doesn't have the env variable written on it.

It works locally if I do:

```bash
VITE_SECRET_I_NEED=<this-definitely-works> npm run build
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: In your code, try accessing the variable with `import.meta.env.VITE_SECRET_I_NEED`. For reference see [this](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files)

Comment: @Bunny I do. The actual build output is this: `{BASE_URL:"/",MODE:"production",DEV:!1,PROD:!0}.VITE_SECRET_I_NEED`. The variable I need is not set.

Comment: I think this is intentional. The environment variable is supposed to be hidden. Can you check the value of the variable in the code itself through console logging maybe? Also check out this [discussion](https://github.com/ElMassimo/vite-plugin-environment/issues/1) which might be relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it under "*Repository secrets*" in Settings > Secrets and variables > Actions (github.com/{username}/{repo}/settings/secrets/actions#repository-secrets)

Then the above job will work if your code reads it via `import.meta.env.VITE_SECRET_I_NEED`